# columns "reference_sequence" of relations "api_variant" does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django to write an app.

I defined a model with following code

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    partOf = models.TextField()
    rawFile = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    CHROM = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    start = models.IntegerField()
    end = models.IntegerField()
    ALT = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    FILTER = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    info_name = models.TextField()
    info_description = models.TextField()
    info_value = models.TextField()
    reference_sequence = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    sample_sequence = models.TextField()
    format_name = models.TextField()
    format_description = models.TextField()
    format_value = models.TextField()
```

then a view to write into the model:

```
def readVariantToDb(request):
    variant = Variant.objects.create(
              partOf = '',
              rawFile = '',
              CHROM = '',
              start = 0,
              end = 0,
              ALT = '',
              FILTER = '',
              info_name = '',
              info_description = '',
              info_value = '',
              reference_sequence = '',
              sample_sequence = '',
              format_name = '',
              format_description = '',
              format_value = '')
    variant.save()
    return HttpResponse('File Read')
```

then the system displayed this:

```
column "reference_sequence" of relation "api_variant" does not exist
LINE 1: ...", "info_name", "info_description", "info_value", "reference...
                                                             ^
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: maybe you add that model without deleting the database and sync again. Look at your database if the field is in the Variant table

Comment: i checked, it's in the database; however, i wiped the table, create it, and sync it again; still doesn't work...

Comment: Try to put default value in that field

Comment: still doesn't work. i set default value to each field in model definition and create an instance with Variant.objects.create(), with no parameter(i wiped and re-create the table again too); but the same error is still there